# How can I save a FileStreamResult to a local file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, filestream

I am able to save string "aaa" to the user's local machine c:\myDir\myFile.txt by using this code in the View:

```
var Test = function() {
var sSelection = getselection();
$.get('/Archive/Save',
 { 'selection': sSelection },
 function (response) {
     var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"),
        theFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\\myDir\\myFile.txt", true);
     theFile.Write('aaa');  //--->> Successfully write "aaa" to c:\myDir\myFile.txt
     theFile.Close();
  }
 );
}
```

But, the Controller returns FileStreamResult, and when I do the following code, I get the error "JavaScript runtime error: Invalid procedure call or argument":

```
var Test = function() {
var sSelection = getselection();
$.get('/Archive/Save',
 { 'selection': sSelection },
 function (response) {
     var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"),
        data = response,  // this is FileStreamResult
        theFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\\myDir\\myFile.txt", true);
     theFile.Write(data);   //----->>> JavaScript runtime error: Invalid procedure call or argument
     theFile.Close();
  }
 );
}
```

This is the code in the Controller:

```
public ActionResult Save(string selection)
{
  int cnt = SetTempData(selection);
  FileStreamResult fs = ArcTicket(0);
  return fs;
}
```

How can I save a FileStreamResult to a file ?
Thank you.

Comment: since its a `.txt` return `string` from Save Action, not FileStramResult

Comment: Sorry, I actually want to save to PDF file C:\\myDir\\myFile.PDF, not a TXT file. This is the code in Controller to create the PDF file:
Byte[] pdf = MvcApplication.Fop.Write(enumFobFormat.Pdf, data                                , Server.MapPath("/Resources/xslt/Ticket.xsl"));
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(pdf);
FileStreamResult fs = new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf");
So, I can't return a string.

Comment: do you really need to save the file to specific location `C:\\myDir`? since `ActiveXObject` only works in IE.

Comment: This is an intranet system, and we only have a couple users, and they only use IE. I want to save the file to the user's local drive, so that after that I can do return window.open("file:///C:/myDir/myFile.pdf") to show the PDF file on a new IE tab. Then, the user will be able to drag and drop that file from that new tab to their email.

Comment: I prefer to **FileResult** instead of **ActionResult**. You can use **return File(fileBytes,System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName)** function or other overloads of this too.

Comment: Thank you. Once the View receive the FileResult,how do I save it to user's local file ?